# How can I open certain links in Google Chrome, which is not my default browser?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

My default browser is Safari. I would like to open all Google Meet links (e.g. `https://meet.google.com/xxx-xxxx-xxx`) to open in Google Chrome. I open these links from a calendar event in Apple's Calendar app.

How can I make these kinds of links open in Chrome instead of Safari?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a browser picker app for this. You configure it to be your default browser, and via rules you set within the app determine which actual browser it then hands the URL off to.

Browser pickers:

- [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com) *(paid)*
- [Velja](https://sindresorhus.com/velja) *(free)*
- [OpenIn](https://loshadki.app/openin/) *(paid)*

Answer (score 6):

You have several options:

**Set Chrome as your default browser** - If you have no trouble in using Chrome, then you can set it as your default browser.

To do this:

Click on the Apple menu and select System Preferences.

Choose the General tab.

Just over halfway down, there's a menu next to “Default web browser.” Click on it and choose the browser you want to set as the default.

**Copy and paste the link** - Though highly manual, you can copy and paste links into Chrome if you don't have a lot of them.

**Use a third-party software** - There are some third-party software that could offer this. As mentioned in @Craig Stodolenak' answer it looks like [Choosy](https://www.choosyosx.com/) could do this. I am not affiliated with the software.

> I understand what you are trying to do but there's only one setting for a default browser in OS X in System Preferences > General > Default web browser

([Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7556829?answerId=30177535022#30177535022))

I asked a question about this on Stack Overflow [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370468/applescript-to-open-a-url-from-calendar-using-google-chrome-depending-on-the-fir/54380206#54380206)

> Here is an *alternative solution*, tested under **macOS High Sierra
>   10.13.6** and it worked:
>
> - **Automator** > **New** > **Service**
>
>   - With settings: **Service receives selected *text* in *Calendar***
> - Add a **Run Shell Script** *action*, with settings:
>
>   - **Shell:** */bin/bash*
>   - **Pass input:** *as arguments*
>   - Replace the *default code* with: `open "$1" -a "Google Chrome"`
> - Save it as: **Open URL in Google Chrome**
>
> Then in Calendar, right click on the **URL** and select **Open URL in
>   Google Chrome** from the **Services** context menu.
>
> *It's not a single click scenario, but gets the job done.*

Comment: AppleScript sounds like an interesting solution. Can you point me in the right direction for that? I'm not much for programming, or even scripting. 

Comment: @Patience sorry, but as i do not own a mac i can't really guide you

Comment: you might be in luck, i posted an SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370468/applescript-to-open-a-link-in-chrome-depending-on-the-first-part-of-it/54372105#54372105 and got an answer

Comment: @Patience got a solution from an so answer, edited post